# Token unknown in SQLCODE

Tags: sql, sql-server, firebird

```
CREATE DATABASE test.fdb -user ZZZZZ -password *******;
```

I am using above command to create a database for my project in windows 7. I am new to Firebird SQL, I used my system credentials for log in but it is showing some error. So, How can I reset my password?

```
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown.
```

I don't even know the significance of **SQLCODE = -104**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error shown is not caused by not knowing the database password, you have a syntax error in the `CREATE DATABASE` statement. The error *Token unknown* means that the statement parser read something it didn't expect; the error is usually followed by the offending token.

If I execute your statement using ISQL on Firebird 3.0, I get the following full error:

```
SQL> CREATE DATABASE test.fdb -user SYSDBA -password *******;
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42000
SQL error code = -104
-Token unknown
-test
```

Which means that at (or before) `test` something in your query is wrong.

The right syntax for [`CREATE DATABASE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-db-create) is:

> ```
>  CREATE {DATABASE | SCHEMA} '<filespec>'
>  [USER 'username' [PASSWORD 'password']]
>  [PAGE_SIZE [=] size]
>  [LENGTH [=] num [PAGE[S]]
>  [SET NAMES 'charset'] 
>  [DEFAULT CHARACTER SET default_charset
>    [COLLATION collation]] -- not supported in ESQL
>  [<sec_file> [<sec_file> ...]]
>  [DIFFERENCE FILE 'diff_file']; -- not supported in ESQL
>
>  <filespec> ::= [<server_spec>]{filepath | db_alias}
>
>  <server_spec> ::= servername [/{port|service}]: | \\servername\
>
>  <sec_file> ::= FILE 'filepath'
>  [LENGTH [=] num [PAGE[S]] [STARTING [AT [PAGE]] pagenum]
> ```

In other words your statement should be:

```
create database 'test.fdb' user SYSDBA password '*******';
```

So:

- Quotes around the path to the database file (or alias)
- No `-` before the `user` and `password` clause
- Quotes around the password (contrary to the syntax shown, quotes are optional around the user name)

As an aside, the *SQL error code* is usually not very interesting (as some of them can cover several different errors).

Comment: is Firebird  case sensitive ?

Comment: @kvk30 When it comes to statements: no (so `CREATE DATABASE ...` and `create database ...` both work), but when it comes to object names: they possibly are. Unquoted object names are case insensitive (they are stored uppercase), quoted object names are case sensitive (they are stored as is), see also http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-structure-identifiers.html

Comment: How can I reset my password for Firebird 2.1?

Comment: @kvk30 As I commented on the other question: get the `security2.fdb` of a clean Firebird 2.1 install so you know that it is `masterkey`. Passwords are not stored in individual databases, but in a central security database (although Firebird 3 offers different options). BTW: If you are starting fresh with Firebird, why not use Firebird 3 instead?

Comment: link for Firebird 3 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117386/discussion-between-kvk30-and-mark-rotteveel).

Comment: can you please provide the link to getting started for firebird?

Comment: @kvk30 http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/documentation/ (or just http://www.firebirdsql.org/ )